# High CPU usage by ntoskrnl.exe!KiStartSystemThread

Tags: windows, drivers, cpu-usage

I have noticed that from some time my system is freezing and its probably caused by the high CPU usage which is caused by the system process.

I have installed Windows Performance Toolkit, and here's the result but i didn't get the idea what is the issue
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nawMi.png

Comment: Why have you added the linux and ubuntu tags?

Comment: Maybe try also Admin Tools, Resource Monitor. Make sure the CPU line is expanded. It is simpler to look at. Let it run for 10 - 15 minutes and see what process is causing the issue. Then look in Task Manager and further try to determine what is happening. Get the Driver Update App for your computer and update all drivers.

Comment: It seems there may be a hardware error. PSHED.dll is platform-specific hardware error driver. Check if anything is showing up in Event Viewer.